# Swift, How to pass multiple type of closure?

Tags: swift, function, closures

```
func test1(user: String, completion: @escaping (TestModel) -> Void) {
    test2(user: "test", completion: completion as! (Any) -> Void //failed here)
}

func test2(user: String, completion: @escaping (Any) -> Void) {
    completion(user)
}
```

I want to pass test1's closure to test2, but test2's closure may have multiple type, it get error when run, EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Is it passable to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a misuse of a generic. If you don't care what type is used as the argument to `completion`, type its parameter as Any:

```
func test(user: String, completion: @escaping (Any) -> Void) {
    completion(user)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`completion` in the above method must take an argument of type `T`. So anything that you use as an argument to `completion` must also be of type `T`. So `user` must be of type `T`, i.e.

```
func test<T>(user: T, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void)
{
    completion(user)
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer too. Very nice. If the OP's intention is that the `user` type should _match_ the completion function's parameter type, then this is right (and my answer is not).